# Creating Xamarin ios storyboard interfaces using classes that are not directly or do not inheret directly from InterfaceController

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard

When creating a WatchKit (WatchOS) Interface controller in the storyboard designer/editor, I cannot set it's class to something that is not itself type WKInterfaceController nor an immediate derived child of WKInterfaceController.

Basically in the hope of abstraction and better code reuse, better design overall, I would like to be able to use classes that are how to say, a more distant relative of their base WKInterfaceController

Basically right now it seems that your stuck using the storyboard designer to make a new WatchOS project.  And using the storyboard designer you only have the option to select the WKInterfaceController class:

```
public partial class  WKInterfaceController
```

or one that directly inherits from it:

```
public partial class ChildInterfaceController : WKInterfaceController
```

but nothing else such as:

```
public partial class GrandChildInterfaceController: ChildInterfaceController
```

So is there any way to do this that doesn't risk the chance of getting corrupted when you reenter the storyboard designer at some point?

Note: I've already asked if it is possible to avoid using a storyboard all together, but that has gone unanswered so I'm assuming no.

For clarity I'm talking about this dialog for "class":
[image]

Comment: Refer to the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/ios-ui/creating-ui-objects?tabs=windows

Comment: thanks, though the document doesnt cover how to do what i am asking.  Also that link in in ref to iOS, and i specifically asked about WatchOS.  From all I gather so far there is no way to define a class that inherits from a class that inherits from WKInterfaceController and have it available to selected for use in the storyboard designer.  This is a major limitation.